# php array with image in table

Tags: php, arrays, image, html-table

```
$items = array(
'item1' => array('image' => 'img/image1.jpg', 'title' => 'Item1', 'price' => '1'),
'item2' => array('image' => 'img/image2.jpg', 'title' => 'Item2', 'price' => '2'),
);

foreach($items as $k => $v) {   
    $rows .= "<tr><td><img src='{$v['image']}'></td><td>{$v['title']}</td></tr>\n";
}
```

So I am expecting a table output but get into problems with the image. It does not display, I am guessing that it has to do with the quotation marks? Tried to change them in several ways like `<img src='"'{$v['image']}'"'>` but no luck. So what's the correct syntax?

Comment: Just check the source code of the page in browser. Your code should work, but keep in mind that you are linking to image relative to your current path not to absolute path of your website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it [simple](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php),

```
foreach($items as $k => $v) {   
    $rows .= "<tr><td><img src='". $v['image']. "'></td><td>". $v['title']. "</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still don't work. I do 
echo json_encode($_SESSION['item']);
Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Can you post your code in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), so that we can have a look ?

Comment: Solved it, my problem was with the $_SESSION array and not the table. But you got me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Pl confirm that path of images is correct.

```
<?php
$items = array(
'item1' => array('image' => 'img/image1.jpg', 'title' => 'Item1', 'price' => '1'),
'item2' => array('image' => 'img/image2.jpg', 'title' => 'Item2', 'price' => '2'),
);

foreach($items as $k => $v) {   
    $rows .= "<tr><td><img src='". $v['image']. "'></td><td>". $v['title']. "</td></tr>\n";
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
foreach($items as $k => $v) {   
 $rows .= "<tr><td><img src='".$v['image']."'></td><td>".$v['title']."</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may write your loop as follows:

```
foreach($items as $k => $v) {   
    $rows .= "<tr><td><img src='" . $v['image']. "'></td><td>" . $v['title'] . "</td></tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in that way

```
$rows .= "<tr><td><img src='{$v[image]}'></td><td>{$v[title]}</td></tr>\n";
```

It will work too.